# How do I configure Qt to work with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2010

I downloaded open-source version of Qt from the site and have compiled it with nmake, but I'm having trouble using it in my projects. It seems that Visual Studio can't find the Qt headers, even though I added the paths to my PATH, INCLUDE, and LIB variables. I tried installing the Qt Visual Studio add-in but it only supports Visual Studio 2008.

Has anyone gotten Qt to work with Visual Studio 2010? Or do I have to wait until Qt 4.7 is officially released for Visual Studio 2010 support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditionally VS support was part of the paid licences, with the OS package you only get mingw support.  Things are changing, but might have some rough edges for a while.

OTOH, mingw has a HUGE advantage: deployment.  You don't have to chase around the `vcredist_x86` files and all the associated voodoo.  Just be sure to include all the .DLLs you use and that's it.

Also, there's QtCreator.  It's not as featureful or omniscient as VS; but it does feel a lot nicer and easier to use.  It takes off all the tedious work of nmake, and embeds the UI editors.  And it's cross platform!

honestly, for me VS can drop dead this minute and i won't miss it.

Comment: +! for that, I always used VS but its just becoming far too bloated and slow and (now) flickery. Bring back VC6!!

Comment: Re: QtCreator, I found it much easier to use than Visual Studio for the actual development (especially if you don't have Visual Assist X). You can set it up to use VC2010 as its compiler if you want. VC does a better job generating code for windows than mingw imo.

Comment: @Cogwheel and VS's visual debugger vs gdb in ease of use!

Comment: @Martin Beckett Indeed. TBQH, i'm of the exact opposite opinion about VS as in the answer. It's by far the best IDE on any platform, but I didn't feel like defending that assertion ;)

Answer (score 2):

Either download the [pre-built vs2008 package](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/windows-cpp-vs2008) or build it using cmake's vs2008 profile and then open the resulting .sln file in vs2010 and let it do the conversion.

edit - annoying feature so far is that the vs plugin doesn't support vs2010 which makes it essentially impossible to use for desktop app development.

Answer (score 0):

Qt V4.8.0 contains prebuilt binaries for Visual Studio 2010 so you don't need to build manually anymore:
http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/windows-cpp-vs2010